# The registry refers to a nonexistent Java Runtime Environment installation or the runtime is corrupted error

Tags: java, java-11, zap

I have an Owasp Zap program that was working fine on java8, Windows 10. Recently, I upgraded to Java 11 as our automation project will not run on anything else. I have removed Java 8 folders from my C: drive and edited the environment variables and everything works fine except for Zap, which gives the error:

> This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 1.8.0. The registry refers to a nonexistent Java Runtime Environment installation or the runtime is corrupted.

I went to my registry but under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\` there was only references to the 11.0.5 jdk

I don't have anything in my environment variables pointing to the old jre as far as I can verify.

I don't have java 8 in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features, although maybe when I deleted it, I deleted manually and should have ran a cleanup program.

Following some advice here, I looked for a jvm.dll file in Runtime Lib in my registry, but I don't even see a Runtime Lib. I also don't see any of the other java related folders other people mentioned finding in their registries that fixed this problem for them. This is what my registry looks like:

[image]

Also I noticed in Control Panel > Programs, there is a link for Java referring to the Java Control Panel, but it is a blank file icon, and when I click it, i get the message "Application not found"

Unfortunately, IT took my admin rights so I can't uninstall and reinstall Zap, but I'd love to solve this this weekend if it's possible.

Comment: FYI, I still am curious to how this would be solvable, however after composing this, I realized I was able to just run the windows batch file from inside the ZAP folder and running it as a java program isn't necessary

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you'd done a clean uninstall things would have behaved properly.

Comment: @kingthorin quite possibly, this is why I can't stand when orgs won't give admin rights to QA but will give them to Dev

Answer (score 0):

I have uninstalled the old runtime and download the offline installation from https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp. After installing the offline installation it's working fine for me.